# To find characters between characters of certain length on the left and right within a string

Tags: excel, function

Within a string like '123456a..aX' I want to find all the 'a..a' between '123456' and 'X'. I can't figure out a way to do this with LEFT or RIGHT or MID. What is the most simple way to solve this problem?

---

Edit:

There are a number of 'a' in 'a...a' in the string '123456a...aX', seven for example, and what I want to get is 'aaaaaaa'.

Comment: I mean I wish to subtract 'a...a' with unknown length from the string

Comment: Include your output screenshot or data in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use text to column feature under Data tab with **a** as separator,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
abc123456The quick brown foxXxyz
```

Formula:

```
=REPLACE(REPLACE(A1, FIND("X", A1, FIND(123456, A1)), LEN(A1), TEXT(,)), 1, FIND(123456, A1)+5, TEXT(,))
```

Of course, if you have `X` anywhere within the text you wish to parse you will run into problems.

[image]

Comment: That's much more complex than I thought... Thanks!